# Scrum vs. Sprint

Tags: scrum, agile, sprint

I'm new to Agile methodology and I have some very basic questions.

Sprint -> It is the iterative process (One development life cycle from Requirement to user acceptance testing) in Scrum.

So, while doing delivery to the client, we say that Sprint 1 and Sprint 2 etc. would deliver?

Where would we use the term Scrum?

What is the delivery time of one Scrum? 
Please clarify to me the exact difference between Scrum and Sprint in an easy way to understand.

Comment: Have you looked up the definitions?  What is wrong with the definitions on wikipedia or google?

Comment: The "daily scrum" is the standup meeting. Scrum with a capital S is the framework/methodology.

Comment: Daily [Scrum](http://scrumguides.org/) is capitalized.  (Refer to official link not Wikipedia or misinformation.)

Answer (score 3):

[Scrum](http://scrumguides.org/) is the Framework in which a sprint takes place. A Sprint is a defined time period for developing features for a product. The maximum time for a sprint is 30 days (can be shorter but not longer). During a sprint the development team develops new features for the product. When the sprint is finished a new version of the product is available. This product could be shipped to the customer.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of sprint in Scrum is quite simple. Like any other Agile methodology, Scrum is based on iterative cycles. They are called sprints. The length of a sprint may vary from 1 to 4 weeks. It depends on the complexity of the project and the amount of code that is to be written during the sprint. The average sprint lasts about two weeks. Such length is convenient because it allows the developers to write enough code to show the intermediate product to the Product Owner.

Answer (score 1):

Scrum is an agile framework which many claim to work by (but if you actually spend time reading the Scrum documentation, you will see that few actual do).

A sprint is a Scrum iteration (cycle).

I recommend you read the following:

1. [Getting Agile with Scrum](https://www.mountaingoatsoftware.com/uploads/presentations/Getting-Agile-Scrum-Agile-Development-Practices-2010.pdf)
2. [The Scrum Guide](https://www.scrumguides.org/index.html)
3. [The Scrum Primer](https://scrumprimer.org/)
4. [Do Better Scrum](https://www.agile42.com/en/agile-info-center/do-better-scrum/)
5. [How To Fail With Agile](https://www.mountaingoatsoftware.com/articles/how-to-fail-with-agile)
6. [Kanban-vs-Scrum](https://www.infoq.com/minibooks/kanban-scrum-minibook/)

Answer (score 0):

**Sprint**
In product development, a sprint is a set period of time during which specific work has to be completed and made ready for review.

Each sprint begins with a planning meeting. During the meeting, the product owner (the person requesting the work) and the development team agree upon exactly what work will be accomplished during the sprint. The development team has the final say when it comes to determining how much work can realistically be accomplished during the sprint, and the product owner has the final say on what criteria need to be met for the work to be approved and accepted.

**Scrum**
Scrum, the most popular agile framework in software development, is an iterative approach that has at its core the sprint — the scrum term for iteration. Scrum teams use inspection throughout an agile project to ensure that the team meets the goals of each part of the process.
The scrum approach includes assembling the project’s requirements and using them to define the project. You then plan the necessary sprints, and divide each sprint into its own list of requirements. Daily scrum meetings help keep the project on target as do regular inspections and reviews.

Answer (score 0):

I also cordially suggest that "Scrum is a *guideline,* not a religion."  It lays out a practical vision and blueprint for *short-iterative* project execution which is to be executed as a series of "Sprints."  The objective is both to help determine *(and, limit)* what the team should set out to do in each iteration, and to quickly bring the product itself back to a "theoretically, at least, deliverable" state.  During the sprint, parts will be carefully laid out across the garage floor, but at its conclusion you should be able to once again start the engine and drive.  The team should learn how to parse off the right amount of work, then to achieve it with high quality without "bustin' themselves," and then how to repeat that again and again.  At the end of each cycle, the product *[more or less]* "works," and the team can *see* it growing according to their plan.

Now, in every case that I've yet worked with, what the team(s) actually did, never was actually "pure, by-the-book methodology," but *[I say ...]* who cares.  They all seemed to benefit positively from *trying* to apply the books' core principles to the dispatching, execution, and quality-assurance of their work.  These principles really do work in a majority of cases, even if a team does not follow them exactly.

Answer (score 0):

**Scrum** is a method agreed within and followed by a team, for the purpose of helping them achieve their objectives with maximum efficiency.

It usually involves a set of meetings with specific agendas, to be held at specific time slots that suit the team.

---

**Sprint** is the minimum frequency at which a team that follows a scrum method can achieve tangible progress that can be demonstrated to the business owners or customers.

It is usually a few weeks (Commonly 2 weeks).

---

**More information:**

Cambridge dictionary provides a very good description for the word 'scrum'.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/scrum

Answer (score -2):

Scrum is like the *< insert holy book here >*. It tells you how you should behave, what principles you should follow and what special ceremonies occur in a cycle of time.

A sprint is like the year. You try your best to live by that codex while you solve the problems that are thrown at you. You observe the ceremonies of sprint planning, review and retrospection as laid out by Scrum.

Answer (score -2):

Scrum is a meeting. The term comes from the name for the huddle in Rugby. In AGILE it is the same as a daily stand-up. Essentially it is a small meeting of the team on a daily basis to make sure everyone is on the same page, and to identify risks to delivery early. [Daily Scrum](https://www.scrumguides.org/scrum-guide.html#daily-scrum)

A Sprint is a window of time. It is usually 2-4 weeks long, decided before the project starts. The Sprint is used to set goals and measure team productivity, as well as any fluctuation to the overall progress and health of a project. [The Sprint](https://www.scrumguides.org/scrum-guide.html#the-sprint)

Comment: The meeting to which you refer is the Daily Scrum, which is often erroneously referred to as just 'Scrum'. Scrum itself is a framework. See http://www.scrumguides.org/scrum-guide.html for more information.

Comment: @sarov This question is posed from within a Scrum framework already, so using Scrum as a term from within Scrum would be shorthand for Daily Scrum. https://www.scrumguides.org/scrum-guide.html#daily-scrum